# Alfresco 5.0.c with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, alfresco, alfresco-share

Using Alfresco for the first time and totally depending on the Manual/Internet resources.

**Stack:** 
Windows Server 2012 
Alfresco Community 5.0.c on PostgreSQL

**Trying to:**
Integrating Active Directory, so that users from the domain can access Alfresco from the domain accounts.

**Query**: 
I found the section from where these settings can be configured in the documentation.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/adminconsole-directorymgt-ss.html

In a few references I have seen this option being listed on the left dialog under Admin tools but by dashboard doesn't have the option.

Like the image below
http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/kevinr/files/2013/09/DirectoryManagement.png

Can't post pictures as I am new to Stack Exchange.
 *(Apologies in advance if I am asking something very silly here )*

Please assist.

Comment: Why are you reading the Alfresco 4.2 manual while using Alfresco 5.0? Why are you not following the [Alfresco 5.0 manual](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/adminconsole-directorymgt-ss.html) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/auth-example-oneldap-ad.html) from the 5.0  documentation should get you going.

PS: The Admin Console is Enterprise Edition only.